# react-scripts variable is not defined, but webpack working fine

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-scripts

in react, I declared a const variable in a js file, attach it to index.html
in my react file App.js, if I use the variable:

1. run react-scripts start/build got **'myVariable' is not defined  no-undef**
2. run webpack and the html working fine

[my example in codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/var-not-defined-c7e8t?fontsize=14) (notes: codeSandbox example also working fine)

index.html in public folder (added config.js)

```html
 <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
  </body>
```

index.html in dest folder generated by webpack

```html
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

config.js (declared the variable server)

```js
const server = 'my server';
```

App.js (use the variable directly in react script)

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      this is server: {server}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would like to know:

1. is it possible to get through the compile error when using `react-scripts start/build`?
2. by using webpack, how to check this kind of undefined variable issues?

additional question:

3. how to check no-unused-vars by using webpack/webpack-dev-server?
   e.g. using `react-scripts start` can get warnings: `'myVariable' is assigned a value but never used`

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should export variable then import it inside `App.js`

```
export const server = 'server';
```

then import:

```
import {server} from '../public/config.js'
```

and with this approach, there will be no need for importing `config.js` script to your Html file.

I see you have your own `webpack.config.js` file in your project and you have also created the project with `create-react-app`.
`create-react-app` uses package named `react-script` which contain its own webpack config file. you can see webpack config inside `node-module\react-script\config`.
it will run `eslint` which is responsible for warnings that you see.

you can disable eslint rules on the `App.js` with adding `/* eslint-disable */` to top of your file and errors on specified file will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
For the import export variables from another file, it is not what I would like to do here. Since import export will bind the values in compile-time, but what I am doing is to import the config.js at runtime, so I can change the values in the file on the webserver for a server config purpose. Hope I could know a better solution. Thanks again.

Comment: also you can set global variable like `/* global server otherVariable*/`
and set unused variable rule like with `/*eslint no-unused-vars: "error"*/`
but there are much better solutions with `.eslintrc` file please visit: http://rahulgaba.com/front-end/2019/02/17/Use-custom-eslint-config-in-create-react-app-using-three-simple-steps-No-external-dependencies.html